# Combining SQL query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with a SQL query and I was wondering if any one of you could use a little of your time to help me.

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
cfd_enc.id,
cfd_enc.version,
cfd_enc.prefijo,
cfd_enc.fecha,
cfd_enc.cfd,
cfd_enc.no_aprobacion,
cfd_enc.tipo_comprobante,
cfd_det.id_orden,
cfd_det.producto,
cfd_det.total
FROM cfd_parametros,cfd_enc LEFT JOIN cfd_det ON cfd_enc.id=cfd_det.id_orden
```

which gets me this:

[image]
(I have 6 rows in cfd_det that share id_orden with cfd_enc.id)

Is there any way I could combine all the repeated rows to get something like this?

[image]

Any help is really appreciated. I'm really stuck, so let me know if you need more specific information.

Comment: You really want what you get, you just dont know why yet ;)

Comment: Tip: You could directly include those Jpgs in the question.

Comment: I'd agree with stefan. What you got in your query is likely what you want. The second output makes no sense for many reasons not the least of which you have repeated column names.

Comment: @Isracg I agree with stefan. Maybe we can help you with the "Why" if you explain why you desire the results be combined.

Comment: there could be a way if there are always N products. But you cannot build a query that will have an arbitrary number of columns

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: @Richard: Technically, you can with Dynamic SQL.  However, it doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: You could do a GROUP BY for every column to reduce the number of rows, but all the values have to be the same.  In your case producto and total are different, so in the end you'd have the same result set unless you remove those.

Comment: The why is, it would be easier for me to read that data, instead of having several rows with repeated info in most columns :)

Comment: @mellamokb  Can't you tell by the field names?  He's using `Le ŜQL`

Comment: I can't see the difference between both representations when traversing the data, apart from less space consumption of course. At first glance it doesn't matter if you are exploring rows or columns.

Comment: I guess it would be easier for me to read the data the way i wanted to, but if there's no easy way to do that guess i'm reading multiple columns hehe.

Comment: @George: Lol.  I meant, where does this data go afterward?  A `PHP` page?  `ASP.Net`?  `Microsoft Excel`?  Printer output?  Just reading it on the screen?

Comment: @mellamokb: Display it in a windows form using C#.

Comment: @Isracg: In that case, it might be easier to format the display of the data on the C# side instead of the SQL side.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, i'm gonna format the data on the C# side instead, as mellamokb recommended :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question - this type of problem actually comes up quite often. It looks like what you're trying to do is 'pivot' rows into columns. Similar questions have been asked/answered elsewhere on SO:

[[SQL Server 2005, turn columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428041/sql-server-2005-turn-columns-into-rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428041/sql-server-2005-turn-columns-into-rows)

[[How to transform rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347624/how-to-transform-rows-to-columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347624/how-to-transform-rows-to-columns)