# T-SQL Group Rows Into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, grouping

How can I group an (unknown) number of rows into a single row where the set columns determine the grouping?

For example, shift

```
Ref      Name            Link
==============================
1        John            L1
1        John            L2
1        John            L8
2        Steve           L1
2        Steve           L234
```

Into

```
Ref      Name            ...    ...    ...
==========================================
1        John            L1     L2     L8
2        Steve           L1     L234   NULL
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347624/how-to-transform-rows-to-columns)

Comment: You're probably looking for a PIVOT or UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might pivot the table using row_number() as a source of column names:

```
select *
from
(
  select ref, 
         name, 
         link,
         row_number() over (partition by ref, name order by link) rn
  from table1
) s
pivot (min (link) for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4])) pvt
```

Simply extend the list of numbers if you have more rows.

[Live test is @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79e65/11).

Answer (score 5):

If the number of different Links is unkown this needs to be done dynamically. I think this will work as required:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ',' + QUOTENAME(Rownumber)
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref, Name ORDER BY Link) [RowNumber]
            FROM    yourTable
        ) d

SET @SQL = 'SELECT  *
            FROM    (   SELECT  Ref, 
                                name, 
                                Link, 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref, Name ORDER BY Link) [RowNumber]
                        FROM    yourTable
                    ) data
                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(Link)
                        FOR RowNumber IN (' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) pvt'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

It is a slight varation of the usual PIVOT function because normally `link` would be in the column header. It basically determines the number of columns required (i.e. the maximum distinct values for Link per ref/Name) then Pivots the values into these columns.

Comment: I have a *maximum* number of links so the above answer works in this case. However, this is useful for future reference - thanks.